# Update columns based on Priority

Tags: sql

Request to please help me with the following updating in SQL table

```
Table Name - Customer Mobile
Table Fields - Mobile1,Mobile2,Mobile3,Mobile4, FinalMobile (Blank)
```

Objective: to Update the  field - `FinalMobile` basis the priority i.e. Mobile1,Mobile2, Mobile3, Mobile4

Basically, I want to update the FinalMobile field basis the priority.

Comment: What have you tried? You could try updating the tables in order of priority.

Comment: This could take multiple iteration; can we do the same in single iteration?

Comment: Why create a column FinalMobile when it is either one of the other four column. You application can take care of that.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the DBMS product you are using